# Android studio gradle error (Android studio 2.1)

Tags: android, android-studio

I get an error message

"A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

Could not download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.21)"

Comment: can you post your application build.gradle and project build.gradle files as well? Also, just to sanity check, were you connected to the internet when you tried to gradle sync/run your project?

Comment: Are you in the right build.gradle file? It should read Module:YourApp and the part where you add dependencies looks like `dependencies {
  compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}`

Comment: Maybe a connection error, Try VPN. or just remove it if you doesn't need it.

Comment: Internet is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Right click on your application/project -> open module settings-> Go to "Dependencies" tab -> you'll find "junit:junit:4.12" -> select it and right click and choose remove option -> ok

Now, build your app again and check if the error is still happened

Comment: Great, it was just a clean problem. Please fill the issue status as answered.